# Editing files on an Ubuntu server from Sublime Text 2 running on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, ssh, sublime-text-2

What's the best way to use Sublime Text 2 running on Windows 7 to edit files that are located on an Ubuntu server?

Emacs has TRAMP which allows the remote editing of files via ssh. Something like that for Sublime Text 2 would be nice.

I'm also considering sidestepping the issue by running Sublime Text 2 on the Ubuntu server and redirecting to an X11 display on the Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 3):

While not quite the same as Tramp, the [SFTP plugin for Sublime Text 2](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) on Ubuntu 12.04 and that seems to be working pretty well.